# Laravel request infinite choices

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to understand how to add multiple variations in the product at the same time.
I'm passing request like:

```
$name = $request->name;
$description = $request->description;
$sku = $request->sku;
$slug = $request->slug;
$type = $request->type;
$category = $request->category_id;
```

And those request are singular, but there is information like prices that will be passed in multiple choices for example:

```
$price_country_id = $request->country_id;
$real_price = $request->real_price;
$sale_price = $request->sale_price;
```

In that case, the user will select a specific country where he wants to sell the product, but the problem is that he can add multiple countries with different prices.
I would need somehow to pass the data in request with those choices and insert them as separate columns in the database.

Front end explanation:
User will have 1 select (country_id) and 2 inputs (real_price and sale_price), he will also have a button to add a new country, that will be infinite (kind of), and in every choice, he will write the same inputs and select another country.

The real question is, how to pass that data and how to foreach them in the controller?

Comment: So one product "has many" prices. Create a table with your products, and another with your prices, define a one-to-many relation between them. The Laravel documenting tells you exactly how to do this.